# VSFTP anonymous upload

Tags: ftp

Im trying to configure VSFTPD to allow anonymous users to upload. For example im trying to upload from cisco router to the linux (CentOS) machine the config files. 
[Here i have post my vsftpd.conf file](http://www.unix.com/linux/245329-vsftp-anonymous-users.html#post302893288)

```
grep -v ^# /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf |grep -v ^$

anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
idle_session_timeout=600
chroot_local_user=YES
ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/ftp/virtual/$USER
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
hide_ids=YES
```

And for the folders i have all configured with 777 etc. and also i have put on all directory "chown -R ftp:ftp pub/" Also i am able to download files from the /pub/upload/ but i cant upload.

Comment: For future reference please post the actual error messages and the relevant configuration settings with the question, rather than on a remote site.

Comment: I love to but the code was too big and i cant find something or i dont know how to post the code without getting too much space, and if it ok to post too big  ... sorry in advanced !

Comment: I've edited your post with a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default for CentOS is to have SELinux enabled. Confirm that with the `getenforce` command.

If in **Enforcing** mode that's the likely reason anonymous FTP uploads are disabled.

Use `setsebool -P allow_ftpd_anon_write=1` to change that policy and you should be able to upload anonymously.

Comment: With getenforce i get this as output
    `[root@centos ~]# getenforce
    Enforcing`
Also i use `setsebool -P allow_ftpd_anon_write=1` and still nothing. Then i disable the "selinux" and from the windows PC using filezilla i can upload but from the router i cant. From the cisco router i use the `copy running-config ftp://ipaddres` and i get `error %Error opening ftp://ipaddress/running.cfg` (Permission denied). I use the full path `ftp://ipadd/pub/upload` and still nothing ... any idea ?

Comment: A quick search found this [Cisco Manual](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-122-mainline/46741-backup-config.html) which seems to indicate that you don't need anonymous FTP at all, specify a username on te Cisco IOS prompt with `#ip ftp username <username>` and `#ip ftp password <password>` and then copy your config with `copy running-config ftp:`  but it has been ages since anyone trusted me to manage their network...

Comment: Ok i will take your way ... but now i have other problems ... this same vsftpd i have configured to work with Berkeley DB and i have configure the cisco VoIP to make backup and it works but now for the running config on the cisco router i have problems. When i execute the copy runn... ftp://<user>:<pass>@<ip> i have error saying wrong user and pass ... but when i try to connect using filezilla also iv got error except when i use port 22 SSH/SFTP ...

Comment: I have successfuly copy the running ... but using the old username and password from voip ... i would like to add new one ... so i just have to change the .db file like change the file.txt and again execute the `db_load -T -t hash -f /etc/vsftpd/virtualfile.txt /etc/vsftpd/virtualfile.db` ???